# why is my <a> tag activating as soon as i open my html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I basically have the href of my  tag scroll to a certain part of my webpage. But every time I reload the webpage, it automatically scrolls to that part of the website without actually clicking it. Does anybody have any idea why this is?

html

```
<div class="arrow">
             <a href="#scroll-to"><span></span></a>
</div>
```

css

```
.arrow span{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin: -10px;
    animation: scroll 2s infinite;}

@keyframes scroll {
0%{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-20px, -20px);
}
50%{
    opacity: 1;
}
100%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(20px, 20px);
}}
```

Comment: If the URL of the address bar ends with `#scroll-to` then that is the reason.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense

Comment: @ITgoldman is correct based on the code and details of your question. When you click on an anchor link such as #scroll-to, that ID will be appended to the end of your URL. So every time you refresh it will anchor to that ID unless you delete it manually or try a new tab. Consider using JavaScript to handle the button if this is a blocker for your project.